# With TIMER1 in CTC mode can't get above ~200khz in arduino UNO runnning @ 16MHZ with no prescaller?

Tags: arduino-uno

I got the following code, and based on the datasheet the Freq should be `clk / 2 * Prescaller * (1 + OCR1A)` making it that if I set the OCR1A to 0, I should get something close to **8Mhz**, but the maximum I can get is **~200kHZ**.  Can anyone help me understand why?

In FAST PWM MODE I can reach those speeds, just wanted to know why i can't in CTC MODE.

```cpp
    void setup() {
  
        DDRB |= (1 << PINB1) ;
        TCCR1A = 0;
        TCCR1B = 0;
        OCR1A = 0;
        TCCR1B |= (1<<CS10) | (1<<WGM12);

        TIMSK1 |= (1<<OCIE1A);
        sei();
    }

    void loop() {
 
    }

    ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
        PORTB ^= 1 << PINB1;
    }
```

Comment: You cannot dispatch an ISR and return fast enough to get anywhere near 8MHz in CTC. But you also cannot do this for Fast PWM mode either. So, I don't know what to make of your question. Did you mean using the actual PWM functionality and just put the ISR in your code as a mistake? Alternately if you were able to get 8 MHz doing this same thing with an ISR and Fast PWM mode, I'm curious to see how.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.

No, i can get the 8mhz using fast pwm without interrupts (yes to your question on the using the pwm functionality), just using the ICR and OCR1A registers and set them to 0. 

I imagined it was something related to the time being consumed by the interrupt calls, but couldn,'t figure out the timings that jumping to the ISR takes.

Comment: I even went to the Microchip IDE and emulated the atmega, but it doesn't implement the ISR very well (either that or i don't know how to), cos i could only trigger the the ISR call when "playing" the debug and couldn't trigger it using the step by step instruction but i manage to get that for a 8MHZ clock the isr was triggered every 5us or something like that i think it was 38 instruction cycles, or close to that, but i coulnd't figure out where did those instructions came from.

Comment: I think i got thrown off by this on the atmega datasheet : The waveform generated will have a maximum frequency
of fOC1A = fclk_I/O/2 when OCR1A is set to zero (0x0000). The waveform frequency is
defined by the following equation:

So i was expecting a ~8mhz pulse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disassembled your program. Below is the code for the ISR. Next to each
instruction, I wrote the number of CPU cycles it takes, as a comment:

```lisp
; Prologue: save some registers to the stack.
push r1         ; 2
push r0         ; 2
in   r0, 0x3f   ; 1
push r0         ; 2
clr  r1         ; 1
push r24        ; 2
push r25        ; 2

; ISR body: PORTB ^= 0x02;
in   r24, 0x05  ; 1
ldi  r25, 0x02  ; 1
eor  r24, r25   ; 1
out  0x05, r24  ; 1

; Epilogue: restore registers and return.
pop  r25        ; 2
pop  r24        ; 2
pop  r0         ; 2
out  0x3f, r0   ; 1
pop  r0         ; 2
pop  r1         ; 2
reti            ; 4
```

I count a total of 31 CPU cycles, most of them spent in the
prologue and epilogue. Then, there is some overhead:

- The CPU always executes at least one instruction of the main program
  between two interrupts. Given that the main program is in a tight loop
  containing only two double-cycle instructions, that will take two CPU
  cycles.
- The CPU takes four cycles to enter interrupt mode: prevent nested
  interrupts, save the program counter and load the address of the
  interrupt vector.
- The interrupt vector is a `jmp` instruction that jumps to the ISR.
  This takes three cycles.

The minimal interrupt period is then given by this sum:

```
 2  one loop instruction
 4  enter interrupt mode
 3  jump to ISR
31  execute ISR
────────────────────────
40  total cycles
```

This takes 2.5 µs, giving an interrupt frequency of 400 kHz.
Given that you need two interrupts for a full cycle of the output
signal, the maximum you can see on the output is then 200 kHz.

You can save 10 CPU cycles by toggling the pin with:

```cpp
    PINB |= 1 << PINB1;
```

This line compiles to a single double-cycle `sbi` machine instruction.
As this instruction doesn't access any CPU registers, you don't need to
save and restore `r24` and `r25`. Actually, you don't need to save and
restore any register, so you could just remove the prologue, and replace
the epilogue by a single `reti` instruction:

```cpp
ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect, ISR_NAKED) {
    PINB |= 1 << PINB1;
    asm("reti");  // return from interrupt
}
```

This gives an ISR that executes in six cycles, and the total interrupt
period can then be as small as 15 cycles. Beware though, that you
should not write a naked ISR unless you are absolutely sure that the
code within it will not clobber any CPU register, nor the status
register.

---

**Clarification**: On the face of it, the instruction

```cpp
PINB |= 1 << PINB1;
```

seems to mean: “Load `PINB`, do a bitwise OR with `0x02`, then write the
result back to `PINB`”. This is, however, not how the compiler
interprets it. Instead, it takes it to mean “set bit 1 of register
`PINB` to one”. This happens to be a single machine instruction, as
`PINB` is a bit-addressable I/O registers.

Yes, the avr-gcc compiler may be a bit peculiar in this respect.

Comment: First of all, thanks so much for that detailed explanation. i did tried to include that ISR_NAKED option, and it doubled the frequency.

One thing i didn't understand is that you said you can toggle the pin with the |= ? i tried it and it stays always on, i can only toggle with the ^= operator, am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: `PINB |= 1 << PINB1;` can just be `PINB = 1 << PINB1;`

Comment: But that doesn't toggle the pin, do i need to set any register?

Comment: @NunoSantos the behaviour of writing to  1-bit to PINx causes that pin to toggle in PORTx. I know it looks weird, but that's how it works on these chips.

Comment: Wait, not sure if i totally understand you, bare with me, i'm a noob...

So, i had the pin toggling, with the XOR operator., but when i change to the OR ou even just setting the pin with the Equal sign, i get no tggling on that pin, after reading your comment i went to the datasheet because i remember reading that there was one bit in a register that did just that, so i updated my code with the line TCCR1A |= (1<<COM1A0); and NOW it toggles if i set the PIN to HIGH inside the interrupt, not sure if it was this you were talking about.

Comment: Cos in my posted version of the code, when i switched the XOR for the OR or just pin assignment, i get no toggling on that pin.

Comment: @timemage: `PINB = 1 << PINB1;` is no faster than `PINB |= 1 << PINB1;`. Also, setting the pin with `=` clobbers a CPU register that you would have to save and restore. You then cannot do without the prologue and epilogue.

Comment: @NunoSantos: You should not replace a XOR by an OR: you should replace `PORTB ^= 1 << PINB1;` by `PINB |= 1 << PINB1;`. Notice that we are acting on a different I/O register: `PINB` instead of `PORTB`.

Comment: @EdgarBonet regarding the faster part, that wasn't the point of it. Regarding the second part: odd.

Comment: Ohhhh i see now, you are setting the PINB not the PORTB, i just tried and works without setting the COM1A0 bit, why is that? why setting the PIN directly toggles a pin off?

And once again, thanks for you time, and sorry for this noob questions

Comment: with your code i get 517kHZ, thats more than double what i had before.

Comment: @NunoSantos: The AVR I/O ports have this toggle functionality built-in. It has been piggy-backed on the `PIN` register, for which a write operation would otherwise be meaningless. Likely a way to save on I/O address space. See the ATmega datasheet.

Comment: @EdgarBonet i was reading the datasheet, and the PINx register is marked as a R only register, while the PORTx and DDRx and R/W, but this is good to know, altough even if you write to them the change won't stay, it's nice to have that functionality. Didn't know that! Thanks so much.